# Rails ajax append single item from collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, append

In my app I have a commenting system in place that displays comments as a collection and I've got ajax commenting working but currently it renders the entire collection again but what I want is to just append the latest comment. Here's my code:

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_member!
before_filter :load_commentable
before_filter :find_member

def index
   redirect_to root_path
end

def new
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new
end

def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.member = current_member
    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
          format.html { redirect_to :back }
          format.json
          format.js
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :back }
          format.json
          format.js
        end
    end 
end

def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.member == current_member || @commentable.member == current_member
          @comment.destroy
          format.html { redirect_to :back }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :back, alert: 'You can\'t delete this comment.' }
        end
    end 
end

private

def load_commentable
    klass = [Status, Medium, Project, Event, Listing].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"] }
    @commentable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
end

def find_member
    @member = Member.find_by_user_name(params[:user_name])
end 

end
```

**statuses_controller**

```
def show
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @status
    @comments = @commentable.comments.order('created_at desc').page(params[:page]).per_page(15)
    @comment = Comment.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { redirect_to profile_path(current_member) }
      format.js
    end
end
```

**statuses/show.html.erb**

```
<% if member_signed_in? %>
    <div id="comm_form_wrap">
        <%= render "shared/comment_form" %>
    </div>

    <div id="comments_<%= @commentable.id %>">
        <%= render partial: "shared/comments", :collection => @comments, :as => :comment %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**shared/_comments.html.erb**

```
<div id="comment_<%= comment.commentable.id %>_<%= comment.id %>" class="comments">
    <span class="comment_av">
        <%= comment_avatar_link_2 comment.member, :class => "com_av", title: comment.member.full_name, alt: comment.member.full_name %>
    </span>
    <span>

        <div class="comment_name">
            <% if comment.member == @commentable.member %>
                <%= link_to comment.member.user_name, profile_path(comment.member) %> <span class="owner">Creator</span>
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to comment.member.user_name, profile_path(comment.member) %>
            <% end %>

            <% if comment.member == current_member || @commentable.member == current_member %>
                <span class="comment_del">
                    <%= link_to image_tag("Delete.png", title: 'Delete'), [@commentable, comment], remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                </span>
            <% end %>
            <span class="meta">
                <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="com_con">
            <%= Rinku.auto_link(comment.content).html_safe %>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

**comments/create.js.erb**

```
$("#comments_<%= @commentable.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shared/comments', :collection => @comments, :as => :comment) %>");
$('#comment_form')[0].reset();
```

If I just change `html` to `append` in the `create.js.erb` file it will append the entire collection of comments. I guess I could copy and paste the code from my comments partial but that'd be a lot of code and I wouldn't know how to define the variables that way. What's the best way for me to append the single new comment? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this one out. Instead of rendering or appending the collection I could just append `@comment` like so:

```
$("#comments_<%= @commentable.id %>").append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => @comment, :locals => {:comment => @comment}) %>");
```

Then I just needed to create a `_comment.html.erb` partial in my comments folder.